# can't install eventdispatcher2.8 on symfony 3.3

Tags: symfony

i'm trying to install omnypay in symfony 3.3 and i found that i must install the 
eventdispatcher:^2.8 before
using :

```
composer require symfony/event-dispatcher:^2.8
```

but i got error:

```
[InvalidArgumentException]
The service "resolve_controller_name_subscriber" must be public as event subscribers are lazy-loaded.
```

i changed the class (resolve_controller_name_subscriber) to be public and the problem is resolved but i'm not sure if this is the right way